# XML Edit data using XmlDocument in C# <> x </>

Tags: c#, xml, edit, xmldocument

I'm using a XmlDocument in C# to edit my Xml file. I want to edit data like this:

```
<Transform>
  <Position>x</Position>
</Transform>
```

But i don't find a matching method yet. I try to solve this and I get something like this:

```
<Transform>
  <Position Positnion=x>x</Position>
</Transform>
```

Could You give me a method and an easy example how to do this?
Thanks ;)

+++ SOLUTION +++

```
XmlNode formData = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transform//Position");

if (formData != null)
  {
    formData.FirstChild.Value = position.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: You better post your solution as an answer or mark the current answer as correct as it basically is in the solution space. Don't edit your question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think, help you:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transform/Position");
node.Attributes[0].Value = newValue;

xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile);
```